# Xdebug install on Mac with PHPStorm

Tags: macos, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm trying to install Xdebug on the Mac and from the created instructions, I get this output below from http://xdebug.org/wizard.php after pasting in my phpinfo as instructed.  I'm getting stopped on Step 5.  There is no .configure file in my downloaded tar.gz file.  Any thoughts?

```
Tailored Installation Instructions

Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.3.15
Zend API nr: 220090626
PHP API nr: 20090626
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc
Configuration File: /private/etc/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
Instructions

Download xdebug-2.2.3.tgz
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.3.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.2.3
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
Edit /private/etc/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
Restart the webserver
```

Comment: Update:  I found a configure file one folder in named debugclient.  Assuming that was the right one, that got me to the 2nd to last step of cp modules....  However, it cannot find the xdebug.so file anywhere in that folder structure after the make command.

Comment: The xdebug.so was in a different location.  I'm all set on this one.

Answer (score 0):

`xdebug.so` was in the `zend` folders in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`